SystemErr Caused by: com.businessobjects.bcm.exception.FIPSError: Cryptographic library is not FIPS-140-compliant. on WebSphere9
I'm working on (crystal) SAP Business Intelligence Platform update to version 4.3 SP4
But can't figure out how to fix this Error:
A Confidential Channel could not be established.
(FWM 02119) Failed to establish confidential channel
SystemErr     R com.businessobjects.bcm.exception.UnexpectedError: An unexpected error occurred(Cryptographic library is not FIPS-140-compliant.).
SystemErr     R     at com.businessobjects.bcm.internal.BcmRsaLib.random(BcmRsaLib.java:56)
SystemErr     R     at com.businessobjects.bcm.BCM.randomLong(BCM.java:699)
SystemErr     R     at com.businessobjects.bcm.BCM.random(BCM.java:691)
SystemErr     R     at com.crystaldecisions.enterprise.ocaframework.BCMInitializer.run(BCMInitializer.java:35)
SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
SystemErr     R Caused by: com.businessobjects.bcm.exception.FIPSError: Cryptographic library is not FIPS-140-compliant.
SystemErr     R     at com.businessobjects.bcm.internal.BcmRsaLib.CheckStartupErrors(BcmRsaLib.java:30)
SystemErr     R     at com.businessobjects.bcm.internal.BcmRsaLib.random(BcmRsaLib.java:54)

We have a module that trying to establish SSL connection for integrating the Report Application Server Java SDK with the BI platform. BI version 4.3 SP4
Server  WebSphere-9.
SDK Java version used by WAS 8.0
IDE: Eclipse
followed all these steps
Tried to disable disable FIPS 140-2 on server WAS :

Security > SSL certificate and key management > Manage FIPS. -> disable FIPS 140-2 ` (No luck)

Disabled the FIPS on CCM (Central Configuration Manager). How is explained on SAP NOTE 1733909 - Turning ON / OFF FIPS-compliant mode on Windows or UNIX in BI 4.x? (No luck)
What else should be done to avoid the ERROR?
Appreciate for any ideas..
